# Preserving file permissions between Ubuntu and WSL

Tags: 16.04, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As part of my workflow, I have a dual-boot system with Ubuntu 16.04 for development and Windows 10 for other work. I use WSL 1 for smaller linux tasks when I don't want to reboot into Ubuntu. As part of this, I use [Zim](https://zim-wiki.org/) for taking notes and I wish these to be accessible and editable from both native Ubuntu and WSL.

I have stored these notes in WSL's home directory which is accessible to Ubuntu through my mounted Windows system drive under `Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu16.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc/LocalState/rootfs/`. It is not advised to access these files in Windows because it erases their permissions, but I assumed accessing them from another Ubuntu instance should be OK. This works fine and my files are accessible from both OSes. But I am having an issue with file permissons. If it's relevant, I access this location through a symlink in my home directory on Ubuntu.

When I edit or add files from WSL, permissions work correctly and I am able to see and access them in native Ubuntu. But when I create or edit files in native Ubuntu, their permissions seem to be erased on WSL (ie. I have no permissions). I can then `chmod` these files in WSL, but it's frustrating to have to do this every time.

I have made sure users on both Ubuntu and WSL have the same name and password, as well as the same uid and gid (1000). I have noticed that the users are members of different groups. For example, my native Ubuntu user is a member of a group related to Docker, but I don't have this installed on WSL.

Are there any other system settings I need to ensure are the same between OSes to preserve file permissons?

Edit: I've eliminated it being as Zim-specific issue. Even creating a new file in Ubuntu using `touch` will result in it having no permissions back on WSL.

Edit: Here are some more explicit details - maybe they will help someone to see the issue. The folder in which all these files are stored has the following permissions (note that it is a symlink on Ubuntu).

```bsh
# WSL:
drwxrwxrwx
# Ubuntu 16.04
lrwxrwxrwx
```

I have also checked the `umask` settings of both OSes. There seems to be a bug is WSL that automatically sets the umask to 000. Do these need to match?

```bsh
# WSL
umask: 0000
# Ubuntu 16.04
umask: 0002
```

I ran `id` on both OSes and got the following results.

```bsh
# WSL
uid=1000(dominic) gid=1000(dominic) groups=1000(dominic),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),109(netdev),110(lxd)
# Ubuntu 16.04
uid=1000(dominic) gid=1000(dominic) groups=1000(dominic),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),128(sambashare),999(docker)
```

Comment: "Preserving file permissions between Ubuntu and WSL" is not the same as "Preserving file permissions between Docker and WSL" . "my native Ubuntu user is a member of a group related to Docker" Please explain why is that? Because in NATIVE Ubuntu your user is part of a group that has the same name as your user. To me that means you are using docker. And docker has its own security model.

Comment: "Are there any other system settings I need to ensure are the same between OSes to preserve file permissons?" The permissions of the directory directly above where you save the files need to be correct.  There is a command "umask" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask that sets permissions for new files and directories.

Comment: @Rinzwind Re: Docker - Perhaps I worded that wrong. As part of the Docker installation process, I created a new group called "docker", of which my user is a member. But the gid for my user is the same as my username. I've edited these details into the question.
Re: umask - I checked the umask on both. It doesn't seem to be the issue but I have added that in to the question too.

Comment: Please look at this posts and see if this solutions is what you want and it works for you: https://superuser.com/questions/1110974/how-to-access-linux-ubuntu-files-from-windows-10-wsl

Comment: Thanks for the link. The title of that post is what I want, but it seems the questioner actually meant "How to access WSL files on Windows", which is not what I'm looking for unfortunately.

Comment: The C drive is in /mnt/c.  If you symlink a directory from there to your home and edit files in that directory, does the problem still occur?

Comment: I just tested this and the same issue occurs. If I create a file at `/mnt/c` in WSL, I can access it fine in Ubuntu (with the drive mounted under `/media`). But if I create a file on this drive in Ubuntu, it has no permissions when I try to access it from WSL. Perhaps this suggests that, even though the WSL file system is meant to be fully linux-compatible, it isn't really because it's still stored on an NTFS-formatted disk?